# Trying to get a bot to type out a list with a delay inbetween

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Trying to get this bot to send a message going 1 to 20, one at a time with a delay in between each message. Running into an error where it has no delay and just spams 20 out with no delay.

```
bot.on('message', function(message) {

let prefix = botconfig.prefix;
let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
let cmd = messageArray[0];
let args = messageArray.slice(1);

    if (cmd === `${prefix}loop`){
      var i;
      while(i < 20){
         var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 2000)
         function myTimer(){
            message.channel.send(i);
         }
         i++;   
      }
    }
});
```

I would appreciate any help or if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an interval that prints and increments `i` every second and then destroys the timer if it's reached 20.

```
if (cmd === `${prefix}loop`) {
  var i = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    message.channel.send(++i);
    if (i === 20) clearInterval(timer);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much I really appreciate it! ^_^